# Primality Testing in $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})}$?

Tags: number-theory, computational-complexity, primality-test

What is known about the computational complexity of primality testing in $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})}$ where $d$ is a square-free number?  For what values of $d$ is primality testing easy (i.e., can be determined in polynomial time)?

Comment: You mean in the ring of integers of a quadratic number field?

Comment: Yes, sorry.  I have edited my question—hopefully it is clearer now.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ isn't the full ring of integers if $d \equiv 1 \bmod 4$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$, primality testing in $\mathcal{O}_K$ reduces to primality testing of integers. It's known that the prime elements $\alpha \in \mathcal{O}_K$ are either

- elements whose norms $N(\alpha)$ are prime, or
- elements whose norms $N(\alpha)$ are squares of a prime $p$ such that $\left( \frac{d}{p} \right) = -1$.

(A slight modification is necessary in the case that $d \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ and $N(\alpha) = 4$. In that case $\alpha$ is prime if and only if $\frac{d-1}{4}$ is odd.)

The first condition can be tested for in polynomial time by the [AKS primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test). The second condition can be tested for in polynomial time by AKS and quadratic reciprocity.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, is there a result stating this? Could you perhaps point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Siddharth: probably this result can be found in most textbooks on algebraic number theory, possibly as an exercise.